# jQuery Unique Name Selector

Tags: jquery

I have multiple groups of checkboxes and radios.
Each group has a unique name attribute but I do not know these names.

I'm looking for a selector to get each group and then loop through them to make sure at least one item is checked.

Obviously I can do an each and compare the names, create an array of unique ones and then loop through the array but I'd rather do it all in one each to be more proficient.  Suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us some markup so that we can help? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't think it's going to get much easier than you've described.

Comment: I don't think css 3 has selector for the logic you are describing, at the end you are going to need what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the elements and store the count for each group as properties in an object. Example:

```
var names = {};
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    names[name] = (names[name] || 0) + ($(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0);
});
$.each(names, function(i, e){
    if (e == 0) {
        alert('No checkbox in group ' + i + ' is checked.');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d4mTs/

Comment: You are doing two each statements which is what I was trying to avoid.  But pretty code regardless.

Comment: @ResidualEnvy: The second one is for looping through the groups in the result. You can't do it all in one single loop, because you don't know if there are no checked checkboxes in a group until you have looped through them all, unless you already have all the groups and how many checkboxes there are in each group.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution (forked from Guffa), using jQuery's :checked selector.

```
var names = {};
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if (names[name] == null)
    {
        var c = $("input[name='" + name + "']:checked").length;
        names[name] = c;
        if (c == 0)
            alert('Not checked: ' + name);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h8ayM/